# Assigning ID to a Row in an Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, row

I have a ListView. When an item on the ListView is tapped, it loads a SubView. I want to assign an ID to each row of the ListView, so I can pass that ID along to the SubView. How do I assign a specific ID to each row in the ListView?

Here is how I am currently loading the ListView:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, mArrayList));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem. I got the employee_ids and employee_names from the local SQLite Database, then I created an ArrayList of employeeNamesArray and an ArrayList of employeeIdArray at the same time. Thus, the employeeIdArray[0] would match with employeeNameArray[0], employeeIdArray[1] would match with employeeNameArray[1], etc.

Once the ArrayLists were created, I fed employeeNameArray into the ListView.

Later, in onListItemClick, I retreive the position of the selected ListView row. This 'position' will corrospond to the position in the ArrayLists - thus, if I select the first row in the ListView, the position will be zero, and employeeNameArray[0] matches with employeeIdArray[0]. I grab the coroloating entry from employeeIdArray and push that to the next Activity by using putExtra.

```
public class MyFirstDatabase extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> employeeIdArray = new ArrayList<String>(); // List of EmployeeIDs

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                           

        // Open the database
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydb.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);

        // Query the database
        Cursor cur = db.query("employee", null, null, null, null, null, "employee_lastname"); 

        cur.moveToFirst(); // move to the begin of the db results       

        ArrayList<String> employeeNameArray = new ArrayList<String>(); // Initialize mArrayList


        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            employeeNameArray.add(cur.getString(1)); // add the employee name to the nameArray
            employeeIdArray.add(cur.getString(0)); // add the employee id to the idArray
            cur.moveToNext(); // move to the next result set in the cursor
        } 

        cur.close(); // close the cursor


        // put the nameArray into the ListView  
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,employeeNameArray));          
        ListView lv = getListView();  
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }


    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) { 
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);                
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SubView.class); // when a row is tapped, load SubView.class

        Integer selectionID = Integer.parseInt(employeeIdArray.get(position)); // get the value from employeIdArray which corrosponds to the 'position' of the selected row
        myIntent.putExtra("RowID", selectionID); // add selectionID to the Intent   

        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); // display SubView.class  

    } 
}
```

Comment: if i have a filter enabled then after filter the first result will always produce the 0 position ... so it is not the right way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Hi Chris you already have the position id in your listView, implement the onListItemClick() function.

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);               
      Toast.makeText(this,  "my id to pass along the subview is " + position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
```

if you want assing your own id use setTag()

```
v.setTag("myownID"+position);
```

Comment: I would like to be able to assign an id to each position in the ListView. I do not want the auto assigned value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with a standard [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) You need to extend the ArrayAdapter and overwrite the [getItemId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId%28int%29) method and maybe also the [hasStableIds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#hasStableIds%28%29) method.

You then have to return true in the hasStableIds method and generate your id for the item at the position that is given to your getItemId method.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on this, this easiest way I found was to override bindView of the adapter and set a tag value containing the row's _id on the item - in my case, it was a button in the ListView row.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.note, cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0) {

    @Override
    // add the _id field value to the button's tag
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        Integer index = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        Integer row_id = cursor.getInt(index);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_delete_record);
        button.setTag(row_id);
    }
};
```