# getting an element in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have 3 ListView in fragment and now I need to get the object I clicked to open a new page and show some elements.

The problem is that in my tabs the ListView is populated querying a Sqlite db and when I add element to the list every page starts from 0 while in my DB each element has a different ID.

How can I get the correct element?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Integer pageToShow = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_character, container, false);
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewPersonaggi);

            personaggiDB = new DatabasePersonaggiHandler(getContext());
            ArrayList<Personaggio> personaggi = personaggiDB.getAllPersonaggi(pageToShow);

            // Adatto il personaggio alla grafica della lista
            this.m_adapter = new PersonaggioAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.riga_personaggio, personaggi);
            listView.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);

            // Su ogni elemento della lista aggiungo il click
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Intent singoloPersonaggioIntent = new Intent(getContext(), SingoloPersonaggioActivity.class);
                    singoloPersonaggioIntent.putExtra("idPersonaggio", i);
                    startActivity(singoloPersonaggioIntent);
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
```

As you can see I use this line:

```
ArrayList<Personaggio> personaggi = personaggiDB.getAllPersonaggi(pageToShow);
```

to understand which type of characters get from my DB so each page has different characters.
For example in my second tab `pageToShow = 2` the first element has position 0 but in my DB it has `id = 12` and so on.

Any idea?

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041218/assigning-id-to-a-row-in-an-android-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be Three ways for passing data on list item click.

**1.** First if you want to load the complete data on next page then you should pass the `PrimaryKey` which is `Id` to next screen . To do so you need to get the list item from adapter. In adapter

```
  @Override
    public Personaggio getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }
```

Then get the instance for clicked item.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(listView.getAdapter()!=null){
                Personaggio obj=m_adapter.getItem(position);
                Intent singoloPersonaggioIntent = new Intent(getContext(), SingoloPersonaggioActivity.class);
                singoloPersonaggioIntent.putExtra("idPersonaggio", obj.getId());
                startActivity(singoloPersonaggioIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

**2.** In second case you can directly pass the object to next activity.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(listView.getAdapter()!=null){
                Personaggio obj=m_adapter.getItem(position);
                Intent singoloPersonaggioIntent = new Intent(getContext(), SingoloPersonaggioActivity.class);
                singoloPersonaggioIntent.putExtra("data", obj);
                startActivity(singoloPersonaggioIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

In this case your model class should implements `Serializable`.

```
 class Personaggio implements Serializable{

  }
```

**3.** For a `CursorAdapter` (and consequently a `SimpleCursorAdapter`) the id returns the row id of the table, that is, `_id`. So if you are using CursorAdapter  then you can simply use 4th long pamameter and it should be named as `_id`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(listView.getAdapter()!=null){

                Intent singoloPersonaggioIntent = new Intent(getContext(), SingoloPersonaggioActivity.class);
                singoloPersonaggioIntent.putExtra("idPersonaggio", l);
                startActivity(singoloPersonaggioIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used your 2nd suggestion and it works like a charm!